# Rename key of array of nested object which is state in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, javascript-objects

I have following array of nested object coming from react state:

```
const categories = useSelector((state) => state.category.nestedCategory);
```

Categories have following data:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "63887a03ca16e96af0512f99",
        "name": "all products",
        "slug": "all_products",
        "children": [
            {
                "_id": "63887a53ca16e96af0512f9b",
                "name": "Electronics",
                "slug": "electornics",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "_id": "63887b5b3a8d48488d1474e1",
                        "name": "Cell Phone",
                        "slug": "cell_phone",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "_id": "63887b9c3a8d48488d1474e3",
                                "name": "Android",
                                "slug": "android",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "63887bbb3a8d48488d1474e5",
                                "name": "IOS",
                                "slug": "ios",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "63887bed3a8d48488d1474e7",
                "name": "Clothing",
                "slug": "clothing",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "_id": "6391bef981673ebab711ae95",
                        "name": "Mens",
                        "slug": "mens",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "6391bf3781673ebab711ae97",
                        "name": "Womens",
                        "slug": "womens",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here I have function to rename the key "name" to "label" and "_id" to "value".

```
const newKeys = {
    displayName: "label",
    displayId: "value",
  };

  const renameKeys = (obj, newKeys) => {
    const keyValues = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
      let newKey = null;

      if (key === "children") {
        obj[key] = obj[key].map((obj) => renameKeys(obj, newKeys));
      }
      if (key === "name") {
        newKey = newKeys.displayName;
      }
      if (key === "_id") {
        newKey = newKeys.displayId;
      } else {
        newKey = key;
      }

      return {
        [newKey]: obj[key],
      };
    });
    return Object.assign({}, ...keyValues);
  };
```

I have iterate through array to rename key with the map function inside useEffect hooks:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getCategoryList(dispatch);
    console.log(categories.map((o) => renameKeys(o, newKeys)));
  }, [dispatch]);
```

But, it is throwing following errors, is there any other way to assign the children object key with new name:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'children' of object
```